# Long output lines in Emacs shell buffer (comint-mode) cause "stack overflow in regexp matcher"

Tags: emacs, comint-mode

Occasionally some process will output a very long line in an Emacs shell buffer (e.g. a multi-kilobyte Java class path). This frequently leads to a "stack overflow in regexp matcher" error, leaving the whole Emacs session unresponsive. Which regexp is causing this?

Comment: Does `M-x toggle-debug-on-error` get you a stack trace when this happens?

Comment: Thanks phils. I'll set that and see.

Comment: Sadly no, the stack overflow just hangs the process. But I think the problem is in the process filter. I'm digging into that.